# Add titled marker in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

To find specific program parts easier I would like to add named markers to my code (like bookmarks). Problem with bookmarks is, that they stay at the same line number and not at the same codeline resulting in missplaced marker after almost any change in the source code.
So markers that stay at a specific code line would be breakpoints. As they are having another usage in debugging and cannot be titled, they are likely not an option.

My question is: Is there a way to set markers and "name" them and then later go to them from a list?
A plugin for that would be ok as well, but I could not find anything (maybe because it is to obvious)...

Comment: In Eclipse 4.5.2, my bookmarks move with the corresponding code position when text is inserted / deleted upstream. Once the edited file is saved, the line number of the bookmark is updated in the bookmarks view as well.

Comment: Interesting... Now that you said it, I tested it again and it seems to work in most cases. In one cases though, it does not. When placing the bookmark in front of the declaration of a function and hit Return when the cursor is in front of the declaration, the bookmark will stay at its line number place and well be stuck at that line of code. It will then properly move up and down as supposed to, but not in that case...

Anyways. You have mentioned a bookmarks view. Where do I find that? I checked Window->Show View, but I could not find it.

Comment: Use Ctrl+3 (Command+3 on Mac)  to open *Quick Access* and then type the name of the View (bookmarks) you want to open. *Quick Access* can be used to find just about anything in the IDE, not just Views.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot you both! Especially the bookmark view is helpful! This will save a lot of time scrolling in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bookmarks will move with the code lines, as noted in the comments above.

An alternative is to use **Task Tags**, custom versions of the **TODO** comment markers. In the *Preferences* navigate to Java > Compiler > Task Tags and define a custom one as shown here:

[image]

Then you can insert comments in your code that will produce Task markers, which are visible in the Tasks view.

[image]